# How do i change the navigation bar from Login to the Username after the user logged in?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

here is my navigation bar, and i want the navigation Bar to change from Login to the username of the user immediately after the user logged in. please how do i do it?

```
<div id="NavBar">
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['Username'])){

                    echo $_SESSION['Username'];
                }
                else{
                    echo <li><a href="Login2.php">Login</a></li>        
                }

                ?>
           </li>
            <li><a href="Candidate Profile.php">Candidates Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="Admin.php">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: how you setting the session from page refresh OR ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't clearly state whats the problem with your current code... but I had to guess maybe it snot displaying like you wanted it to be.. well the problem might be the `<li>` tag that you opened and did not close then open and close another one inside of it...

your

the browser reads and interprets you navigation like:

`<li><a...>Home</a></li>
<li>Username<li><a...>login</a></li></li>`

Yo need to close that `<li>` before opening the next unless you are downing a dropdown menu, but it does not look like that in your case.

this how you code should look:

```
<div id="NavBar">
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['Username'])):?>

                <li> <a href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['Username'];?></a></li>
               <?php

                else:?>

                <li><a href="Login2.php">Login</a></li>
                <?php
                endif;

                ?>
            <li><a href="Candidate Profile.php">Candidates Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="Admin.php">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Big thanks to you , you really got my question. Thanks...!!! and it really worked..!!!

Comment: @Daniel If this solved your issue remember to Accept the answer and maybe even give it an Upvote

Comment: but please i want some little help, i don't know you are free to help me, maybe i can get your email and forward you my code and see if you can some little modification on it. trying to fix my final project. we didn't really have much knowledge, only did some few self development and i got basic incite on it, but you are willing to help me i'll be glad, thanks.

Comment: you can add me on google hangouts masivuyecokile@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You didn't exactly say what the problem is but from the looks of it Rearrange your code

```
<div id="NavBar">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
                $username = $_SESSION['username'];

                echo "<li>$username</li>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<li><a href='Login2.php'>Login</a></li>";        
            }

            ?>
       </li>
        <li><a href="Candidate Profile.php">Candidates Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="Admin.php">Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
<div id="NavBar">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
          <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
                echo "<li>".$_SESSION['Username']."</li>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<li><a href='Login2.php'>Login</a></li>";        
            }
          ?>
        <li><a href="Candidate Profile.php">Candidates Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="Admin.php">Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```